# Let holders of Research Assistant badge create new tags, even if they have less than 1500 rep

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges, tag-creation

The primary reason (that I could see) for down votes for [Reputation requirement to create new tags is too high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145171/reputation-requirement-to-create-new-tags-is-too-high) is that users need to be active long enough to earn 1500 rep before they have the experience necessary to avoid creating invalid or unnecessary tags.

I believe that someone who has earned a Research Assistant badge has had enough exposure to the problems that can result from hastily created tags.  I'll also point out there that there are several other tag-related badges that require less work and that some combination of those badges could also qualify a user to create new tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[39 people have that badge on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1656/research-assistant), and [only one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489364/kommradhomer) has less than 1.5k rep (although a few don't have *much* more).  Implementing this would change so little that it just isn't worth the effort.

Comment: kommradhomer's going to save us all.

Comment: Looking at his tag edits, I don't think I'd want him creating tags.  I wouldn't even have approved most of his edits.  Many of them don't say anything useful, and those that do are just copy/paste from Wikipedia (out of the ~10 I checked).

Comment: @Servy - So you're very happy with the new tags added and edits made by all people with more than 1500 rep?

Comment: @ChrisGerken No.  What's your basis for assuming that?  Your suggestion was not for requiring this badge *instead of* having 1.5k rep, it was providing access to these people *in addition to* those with 1.5k rep.  If you really meant "instead of" it would dramatically change my answer.

Comment: What I meant was that someone with the badge but not the points is qualified to create new tags, IMHO.

Comment: @ChrisGerken And my answer to that is there is only one such person in existence, so even if that were true it's not worth implementing.  In addition, looking at their specific history and suggested tag edits they aren't qualified to create new tags.

Comment: I need an "Add Comment" button that makes me count to 10 before pressing it.  I'd put in a feature request, but I'd just lose more rep and be even further from being able to create new tags. :)

Comment: @ChrisGerken It's worth mentioning that rep on meta is separate from rep on SO.  Losing rep here only affects your ability to create tags **on meta**.  Having said that, if you made such a request you can be sure that people would downvote it to oblivion.  The throttling that already exists on comments annoys people to no end.

Comment: I know, but I'm getting further away from even being able to down vote.