# Why so many hurdles?

Tags: discussion

**Hurdle #1**

Its tough being new here.  I answered my first question on the garden site, here: [How can I amend clay soil with soil, without digging?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7657/how-can-i-amend-clay-soil-with-soil-without-digging/7743#7743)  but couldn't properly reference my post because of some 2-link limit imposed.

I used to read a lot on the skeptics board and it left me with the impression this site was about backing up what you're saying with at least some sort of proof and not much about conjecture.  I can't imagine why someone with no reputation would be forced to appear to be conjecturing and unable to provide plenty of links.

**Hurdle #2**

So then, I sign up on the biology board and ask: [Do teeth have the capacity to heal?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/can-human-teeth-heal-themselves) and was forced to write:

> Could a cavity in a human tooth "heal over" or possibly fill back in?
>
> That's really all I wanted to ask, but the site won't let me post without some added clutter. Feel free to edit the question to make it presentable. Thanks.

I can elaborate with the best of them, but sometimes clutter is just clutter.

**Other Hurdles**

The password requirements are **overly** secure and stiffer than any financial institution I've seen.  I can't PM mods to ask for guidance.  It seems I'm continually being told I can't do something.  I can't edit my comments after 5 min... I have to delete it and recomment.  I can't pick the most applicable tags... I have to pick a popular one.

Why so many hurdles?  Why is it so hard to get established here?

Comment: "Why is it so hard to get established here?" Because it makes it so much more awesome when you actually get there.

Comment: Hi Randy, I'm not familiar with the Biology site but I'm not 100% sure whether that kind of question is actually welcome there? It seems to be targeting mainly academics. (Maybe someone from the Biology community can answer that)

Comment: Re the password, yeah... don't forget these sites are run by some very  passionate developers, and they know their theory regarding password strength. :) Don't forget you can always connect with a 3rd party OpenID service like Facebook.

Comment: How would you expect us to answer this question? If your premise is correct, and it is hard to "get established here", the reasons are the ones you mentioned in your question. If you want one (or several) features to be improved, post questions outlining why you think a change is needed and what alternatives we should look at. As your question stands, it is neither a question nor a constructive proposal for improvement.

Comment: @Asad he wants to discuss it, which could lead to eventual relaxing of the restrictions (doubt it though). Perfectly OK for meta.

Comment: @Manishearth Site policy is rarely changed (as you noted) when you just casually point at a bunch of problems and say "make them go away". If you have a problem with a feature, or want to discuss changes to it, make a question specific to that feature.

Comment: @Pekka웃 our scope seems to be reaching further than our tagline suggests, which is something being discussed on our meta, though this question after an edit has got a few upvotes :)

Comment: @Asad Yes, but what about the discussion part? This is in fact something I've had to explain to many others (got a few posts about it on Quora too, iirc) -- "why is SE so overmoderated?" is a very common question.

Comment: @Manishearth I'm not saying the OP has to put in a feature request. I'm saying discussion is much more productive when it is centered on a specific feature. The reasons for this are that you [don't end up missing existing discussion on the topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166010/200500) (you might notice that is a discussion question, not a feature request), and if you arrive at the conclusion that changes need to be made, you can reference the question in any feature requests that stem from it.

Comment: @Asad agree on that :)

Comment: We got rid of the 2 link limit on Skeptics, and the world hasn't ended there (actually I haven't noticed the slightest difference in spam). It might be worth it to try disabling it on other sites as well, or at least improve the notification when hitting the limit to be in real-time, and not only after you try to submit.

Comment: `"The password requirements are overly secure and stiffer than any financial institution I've seen."` - I once worked for an actual bank where the password requirements on their website explicitly forbade all "special" characters because the vendor claimed that "they can be used to run malicious code on the database."  Turns out that (1) passwords were stored in plain text and (2) input wasn't properly sanitized.  Just saying... Simply because something is a financial institution doesn't mean it should be regarded as the gold standard in information security :)

Comment: @Asad Can I help it you're not able to pick a point and elaborate?  The problem is there are so many things working against a new user (many of them downright silly) that he might choose to throw up his hands and walk away.  Is not the goal of these sites to have an answer for every question?  Well how can that be if new users are frustrated with all sorts of restrictions which have no sensible foundation?

Comment: The entry requirements on SE are actually very low; you hardly need to do anything to ask a question - but the ones there are help to keep the quality level up.

Comment: @Randy That's just it; most of these restrictions *do* have a sensible foundation. I'm not going to rehash Manish's answer, but the reason I was suggesting you ask feature specific questions is because most of these problems have already been noted in earlier questions (as you would have found) and either remain under discussion or have been incorporated into the site via feature request. Throwing up your hands and walking away is certainly easier, but you kind of have to meet us halfway here, since SE and the community is sort of making it up as it goes along.

Comment: 2-link limit is sensible?  How many spammers use more than 1 link?  Why can I not edit comments after 5 min?  What sense could there be to that?  Why can't a new user pick whichever tag he wants?  None of these restrictions seem to have any purpose other than to frustrate someone. Yes, once you've gotten established, some of the restrictions go away, but you're not trying to attract established users. You should be trying to attract new users and not have them get frustrated with the barrage of roadblocks. I just thought I'd bring it up while I'm still new and have it in mind.

Comment: @Randy I'm getting tired of repeating this, but if you had addressed each of these issues separately, you would already know that for and against arguments pertaining to these features have already been made. I have no interest in rehashing these, so here's a bunch of links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166010/200500, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33997/200500, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145171/200500.

Comment: `You should be trying to attract new users and not have them get frustrated with the barrage of roadblocks` that isn't necessarily true. We don't want *any* user out there, we want users who understand how things work, and contribute high-quality content.

Comment: @Pekka The roadblocks prevent high-quality content.  Just yesterday I wanted to contribute by comment to a question, but was unable to.  I couldn't answer the question fully, so I couldn't post an answer.  Since I couldn't post a comment either, the person doesn't get to see my input at all.  The roadblocks are silly and prevent contribution.  Its as simple as that.

Answer (score 17):

> Why so many hurdles?

Without these hurdles, we would be a lot like forums elsewhere across the Internet, or like Quora. The tradeoff here is that the more lenient you get, the more your signa-to-noise ratio decreases. SE sites work well because they have strict, enforced, policies.

Note that a lot of the hurdles are with StackOverflow (a huge site in this network about programming) in mind, and I do partly agree that some of them ought to be reduced or removed for smaller sites.

---

> Its tough being new here. I answered my first question on the garden site, here: How can I amend clay soil with soil, without digging? but couldn't properly reference my post because of some 2-link limit imposed.

Well, most new user restrictions get removed at 10 reputation. 10. Extremely easy to get, on any site. And once you reach 200 on a site, you get +100 on all other sites; so you get to bypass most restrictions.

You can always keep the links in a comment (or remove the `http` and ask members to edit it in); this usually works.

This particular restriction is to help battle spam and self-promotion.

> I used to read a lot on the skeptics board and it left me with the impression this site was about backing up what you're saying with at least some sort of proof and not much about conjecture. I can't imagine why someone with no reputation would be forced to appear to be conjecturing and unable to provide plenty of links.

I think the restriction isn't there for Skeptics. Skeptics is ...different in many ways, including policies.

> I can elaborate with the best of them, but sometimes clutter is just clutter.

Sure, but almost always short questions are too broad or vague. Besides that, we expect some research effort put into questions -- what do you already know? What have you already found out about this?

> The password requirements are overly secure and stiffer than any financial institution I've seen.

I actually agree here, but usually OpenID providers try to enforce secure passwords. Don't like it? Use the Google/Yahoo/FB/OpenID.net login.

> I can't PM mods to ask for guidance.

You can't do this on most other sites anyway. And you don't need mods, usually the community will try and help you.

> I can't edit my comments after 5 min... I have to delete it and re-comment.

Comments are meant to be ephemeral, so it doesn't really matter what happens to them. The main focus is on posts, not comments.

> I can't pick the most applicable tags... I have to pick a popular one.

No, you can't *create your own tags*. Usually, the "most applicable" tags are so applicable that they'll only apply to your question(and possibly 1 other). Tags need to be broad so that they apply to many questions. Also, usually a community member will help with this.

Comment: +1 also, we impose restrictions on tags because *they are the most essential ingredient to searching on the site*. If everyone could just pick their tags willy nilly, the result would be a complete chaos.

Comment: Any forum I have been on, I could always PM anyone.  I think mods, at least, should be accessible.  For instance, http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/is-there-evidence-that-a-deeply-watered-lawn-will-develop-deeper-roots  I had someone answer my question in a way I'm not sure how to handle.  Everything said in the answer is wrong and I would like some private guidance from someone with more site experience on how to handle this situation.

Comment: You don't need to PM anyone. If the answer is wrong, either you or another community member can fix it or comment on it.

Comment: So I just go in and change his answer to suit myself?  What's to stop him from changing it back?  This concept is foreign to me.

Comment: @Randy If you see a wrong answer, just comment (and downvote if you have the privs). Others will see the comment and downvote too

Comment: @Manishearth It doesn't seem to work that way on the smaller sites like gardening. I routinely see wrong answers up-voted, correct answers downvoted, and rarely is anything backed up with a reputable reference, its like the wild-west with no government except hardwired laws of the website.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding password requirements and login security - this site is certainly much **weaker** than all the global financial institutions I have worked with in my professional role as security consultant/strategist/assessor. In fact one of our common gripes over on security stack exchange is the low level of security here - we would like it beefed up further:-)

Regarding the 2 link limit - list the URL in your question and ask a community member to add the link. We are really quite helpful like that.

Also, each site is different- Skeptics does require some very definite evidence of claims etc. Gardening, not so much. Have a good look at each site's about page and faq.

Comment: Why does security need to be beefed further?

Comment: That's another gripe... I hit the enter key and my comment was submitted.  The next thing I was going to ask is: And garden information doesn't need to be substantiated?

Comment: Because the security across SE is quite low - and as security professionals we would prefer it meet general industry standards. And as for your 2nd point - not anywhere near as much as on Skeptics, no :-)

Comment: If nothing needs to be substantiated, how is SE different from forums?  What attracted me to SE was the tight-ship mentality and I could always find an answer I could trust.  My trust is waning on the garden site.

Comment: Read what I wrote. You keep saying it doesn't need to be substantiated. That is explicitly **not** what I am saying.

Comment: What of gardening needs to be substaniated and what does not?  It is no different than skeptics.  Info is info and if it isn't common knowledge, then it should be referenced... especially in gardening since gardening is plum packed with wives tales and opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding sending 'private messages' to Mods, moderators are quite accessible within their communities (though not necessarily in private).  For example most moderators check their sites chat room regularly (`chat.stackexchange.com`, [which needs only 20 rep to talk in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat)).

Similarly you can ask public questions on a sites meta (`meta.site.stackexchange.com`)  with only 5 reputation, as long as your question is clear and genuine it will usually get a quick response by a moderator or experienced community user, especially if it's a support question about how the site works.

Finally comments on posts (which can be posted on all posts after you have 50 rep) are often read by experienced members of the community who will provide guidance quite happily in many cases.

It's encouraged to have discussions with moderators out in the open firstly to promote transparency but also to allow other users to be educated and share their own experiences/opinions on a topic.  If you really do need to have a private discussion with the moderation team (I can think of very few reasons why this would be necessary) then your best bet is to ping them in chat and ask them to create a private room for the discussion.

You can find a list of a sites moderators on the users page (but remember that experienced non-moderator users are a good source of information too): `site.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators` and links to both meta and chat personalised per-site are available in the top bar, to the left of the search box.

Comment: You forgot the easiest way of getting a moderator's attention: Flags.

Comment: @Yannis Mmm, I missed them out as it sounded like the OP more wanted to attract moderator attention to ask questions about how the site worked, which I didn't really see as an appropriate use of flagging, but they're certainly there in reserve too

Comment: Well, it's not the best use of flags, but it's neither unheard of nor completely inappropriate. I wouldn't mind it if a new user used a mod attention flag to ask for some help with the site's mechanics once or twice. If they've made a habit of it, I'd probably start declining their flags after a point.

Comment: Questions on how the site works, I can find answers to by reading how the site works in FAQs.  I would need a mod as more of a mentor role on specifics on how to deal with situations of a more private nature, which aren't necessarily offensive or against site rules and warranting a flag.